# Android lifecycle, which life cycle methods are executed in the same message during orientation change?

Tags: android, message-queue, lifecycle

I need some confirmation on some information I just found out recently.

Are the lifecycle methods `onCreate(), onStart() and onResume()` handled together as ONE `message` in the `message queue` during an orientation change?

and on the flip side is `onPause(), onStop() and onDestroy()` handled together as one `message`?

One of the reasons I wanted to know is that if I have a thread that loops infinitely while posting to the main ui thread and I change my orientation, will it always post after `onResume()`? It will never post BETWEEN a lifecycle method right?:

```
private static class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            mainUiHandler.post(myRunnable);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by one message ?

Comment: While this is theoretically interesting (I don't think it's true btw.), it is irrelevant for app programming. You must not make use of it, later versions of Android may change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  At least not as something you can rely on.  Remember that onPause can be called without onStop in some cases.  Same for onStart without onResume.  (in both cases they'll be called eventually if needed).  onDestroy may never be called at all, your app should be written assuming that it won't be for sure.

Comment: O, you're right, I guess I posted the question to quick w/o thinking. I specifically want to know if they get called in one message during an orientation change. I'll updat my question.

Comment: The answer to that is probably, but that's an implementation detail that's not promised to remain the same between versions of android.